# How can I increase the i in a for?

Tags: python

I want to increase in 6 the value of i to read a file that have a question with 4 answers and a character of the correct answer, for example:

```
A
Which sport uses the term LOVE ?
Tennis
Golf
Football
Swimming
B
What is the German word for WATER ?
Wodar
Wasser
Werkip
Waski
```

My code:

```
fd = open(dFile)
lineas=fd.readlines()
fd.close()

for i in range(len(lineas)):
    print "CA:"+lineas[i]+"Q:"+lineas[i+1]+"A1:"+lineas[i+2]+"A2:"+lineas[i+3]+"A3:"+lineas[i+4]+"A4:"+lineas[i+5];
    i=i+6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the "step size" argument to range or xrange:

```
fd = open(dFile)
lineas = fd.readlines()
fd.close()

for i in xrange(0, len(lineas), 6):
    print "CA:"+lineas[i]+"Q:"+lineas[i+1]+"A1:"+lineas[i+2]+"A2:"+lineas[i+3]+"A3:"+lineas[i+4]+"A4:"+lineas[i+5];
```

Answer (score 1):

[`range`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) has an optional `step` argument.

```
for i in range(0, 10, 3):
    print i  # Prints 0, 3, 6, 9
```

For your case, use a step size of 6.

```
for i in range(0, len(lineas), 6):
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippets illustrate a way of treating each group of six lines from the input file as a tuple, which removes some of the clumsy `lineas[i], lineas[i+1]` *etc* indexing (at the cost of a clumsy-looking `zip` statement).  The first snippet of code is just to create a test file containing numbered lines.

```
with open('eh','w') as fo:
    for i in range(19):
        fo.write('{}\n'.format(i))
...
with open('eh') as fi:
    for (ca,q,a1,a2,a3,a4) in zip(*[iter(fi.readlines())]*6):
        print "CA:"+ca+"Q:"+q+"A1:"+a1+"A2:"+a2+"A3:"+a3+"A4:"+a4
```

This produces output like

```
CA:0
Q:1
A1:2
A2:3
A3:4
A4:5

CA:6
Q:7
A1:8
(etc)
```

Note, I would ordinarily write something like

```
print 'CA: {} Q: {} A1: {} A2: {} A3: {} A4: {}'.format(ca,q,a1,a2,a3,a4)
```

instead of

```
print "CA:"+ca+"Q:"+q+"A1:"+a1+"A2:"+a2+"A3:"+a3+"A4:"+a4
```